# Не работает сортировка sorted

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код до строки с `sorted` работает,при работе функции `sorted` сортировка не производится

```
def srtgr(self):
          """Номер группы в порядке убывания по успеваемости"""
          summarks=0#Сумма оценок
          sumsredball=0
          gl=dict()    #Словарь для распределения по группам          
          for s in studinfos:
               sd=gl.pop(s.numbgroup,dict())
               sd[s.surn]=[s.markgeometry,s.markalgebra,s.markinformatika]
               gl[s.numbgroup]=sd
          for k,v, in gl.items():                  
                   s=f'Группа: {k}: \n'
                   for stdn,grds in v.items():                  
                         s+=f'  {stdn}\t{grds[0]},{grds[1]},{grds[2]} \n'
                         summarks += grds[0] + grds[1]+ grds[2]
                         sumsredball = round(summarks / (len(v) * 3), 2)
                   s += f'Средняя успеваемость в группе: {sumsredball} \n'
                   print(s)
          print(sorted(gl, key = lambda x: sumsredball,reverse = False))--Проблемная строка
```

Как видите на прикреплённой картинке, если идёт сортировка по убыванию то должна первая стоят ВМО12,а потом ВМО11.А он последовательно их выводит,как и до сортировки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста прочтите как создать [mcve]

Comment: `reverse = False` — это сортировка по возрастанию

Comment: @andreymal при reverse=True аналогичный результат.

Comment: `key = lambda x: sumsredball` — так как во время сортировки значение sumsredball нигде не изменяется и всегда равно 8.67, все элементы считаются равны друг другу и такая сортировка просто ничего не делает