# Как создать вложенный словарь в словаре через цикл?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно посчитать средний балл в студенческой группе.

**ЧТО У МЕНЯ ЕСТЬ?**

Есть работающий словарь с такой структурой  `{'Номер группы', {'Студенты': [{'ФИО': [оценка1,оценка2,оценка3]} }`

```
{'ВПР11': {'Иванов': [3, 4, 5], 'Петров': [4, 4, 5], 'Сидоров': [5, 4, 5]}, 
 'ВПР12': {'Кузнецов': [3, 5, 4], 'Юрьев': [5, 5, 5], 'Орлов': [5, 5, 5]}}
```

Но чтобы подсчитать средний балл с студенческой группе и после его отсортировать.

А для этого нужна следующая структура `{'Номер группы': {'Студенты': [{'ФИО': [оценка1,оценка2,оценка3] ...}], 'Средний балл': 0}}`:

```
{'ВПР11': {'Иванов': [3, 4, 5], 'Петров': [4, 4, 5], 'Сидоров': [5, 4, 5], 'Средний балл': 4,6}}, 
 'ВПР12': {'Кузнецов': [3, 5, 4], 'Юрьев': [5, 5, 5], 'Орлов': [5, 5, 5], 'Средний балл': 8,4}}
```

**КАКАЯ ПРОБЛЕМА?**

Как я понял, нужен словарь в словаре(вложенный словарь).
Каким образом мне можно организовать вложенный словарь?

Как произвести заполнение словаря в словаре через цикл?

То есть сначала нужно заполнять ключ 1-ого словаря(у меня `gl`),затем после добавления ключа уже внутри словаря производить добавление вложенного словаря(`listgroup`)?

Я попытался это сделать в коде, но при самом добавлении ключа словаря выходит сразу ошибка `TypeError`

```
for s in studinfos:
      sd=gl.pop(s.numbgroup,listgroup(s.surn,dict())) - TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
      for ss1 in studinfos:
              sd1=listgroup.pop(s.surn,dict())
              sd1[s.markgeometry,s.markalgebra,s.markinformatika]=sredball
      gl[s.numbgroup]=sd
```

Comment: А зачем вам добавлять средний балл в существующий словарь? Создайте новый вида {group: score}, а потом выводите его в отсортированном порядке.

Comment: А вообще, можете просто для каждой группы group посчитать средний балл, после чего написать gl[group]['Средний балл'] = score

Comment: @EzikBro вот здесь проблема,я не знаю как это реализовать в отдельном словаре?
У меня есть переменная в конструкторе numbgroup,и её легче добавлять в словарь
А вот переменную среднего балла и по заданию в конструктор нельзя добавлять,а как её сходу добавить в новый словарь я не могу понять.


В данном вопросе,который я поднимал,всё считается внутри словаря, но оно не сортируется потом.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1238192/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все еще не понимаю до конца вашу проблему. Пусть у вас есть словарь словарей листов оценок:

```
gl = {'ВПР11': {'Иванов': [3, 4, 5], 'Петров': [4, 4, 5], 'Сидоров': [5, 4, 5]}, 
 'ВПР12': {'Кузнецов': [3, 5, 4], 'Юрьев': [5, 5, 5], 'Орлов': [5, 5, 5]}}
```

Теперь вы хотите посчитать средний балл в каждой группе. Если я правильно понимаю, то имеется в виду средний балл средних баллов учащихся. Это все делается двойным циклом:

```
for group in gl:
    students_aver_grade = []
    for student in gl[group]:
        aver_grade = sum(gl[group][student]) / len(gl[group][student]) 
        students_aver_grade.append(aver_grade) 
    group_score = sum(students_aver_grade) / len(students_aver_grade)
```

Теперь чтобы добавить эти средние баллы в новый словарь со средними оценками groups_scores нужно во внешний цикл добавить такую строку:

```
groups_scores[group] = group_score
```

Разумеется, перед этим надо до цикла объявить этот словарь.

Теперь чтобы вывести эти средние баллы в порядке убывания можно написать что-то такое:

```
sort_groups = sorted(groups_scores, key=groups_scores.get, reverse=True) 
for group in sort_groups:
    print(group, groups_scores[group])
```

Также вместо словаря groups_scores может быть листом кортежей (группа, балл), которые сортируются и до версии 3.7 питона

Comment: Оно сработало,спасибо!
Теперь я понял наконец-то.